# Better way of comparing two lists of dictionaries and display unique changes

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, hash-map

Can I get a review of my code which compares 2 dictionaries and display unique changes.

```
import time
from random import randrange

temp_data = [{"Name":"SuperFish","KeyID":"SecretCodeFish"},
            {"Name":"CowMan","KeyID":"SecretCodeCow"}]

def check_data(Names):
    temp_key = "SpecialKey"
    temp_list = []
    for item in Names:
        Users = {
            'Name': item['Name'],
            'Status':(randrange(2))}
        temp_list.append(Users)
    return temp_list

def display_data(data):
    for i in data:
        print("===")
        print (i)
        print("===")

Prev = check_data(temp_data)
Curr = check_data(temp_data)
New = []

# Runs Repeteadly
while True:
    Curr = check_data(temp_data)
    time.sleep(3)
    for item in Curr:
        if item not in (Prev):
            New.append(item)
    if len(New)>0:
        Prev = Curr
        display_data(New)
        New = []
    else:
        print("NO CHANGES DETECTED")
```

I'm mainly wondering if there is a cleaner way to write my solution.

Comment: It's doubtful that you should be using a dictionary the way that you are, and should be passing around a stronger type like a named tuple or class instance, but your question is too hypothetical to answer. Surely you're not _actually_ doing what `check_data` is doing every three seconds, but you haven't described your real use case.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: What's with all the temp data and hardcoded values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**General**

Variable names and function arguments should be lowercase.

You should wrap your main procedure in a main function, as well as a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419185/9173379).

Function and variable naming are important for readability of your code. The clearer and more accurate your naming, the quicker and easier your code can be understood. For example: `check_data` does not check any data.

Its argument `names` is not a list of names, but a list of dictionaries that have a name and an id.

If I only see that function signature, I would expect to be able to do `for name in names` and get one name (probably as `str`) after another. Instead I get a `dict`, that has a `"Name"` field. `for item in names` should be an indicator, that `names` should be called something like `items`.

Type hints also make your code easier to read and understand, use them. [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) | [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

---

**`check_data`**

It's not quite clear why this function does what it does. Documentation (comments / docstrings) as to why this function is implemented this way would help.

`temp_key` is never used, delete it.

In its current state, the function can easily be cut down to a single line using a list comprehension:

```
def change_data(items: list[dict]) -> list[dict]:
    return [{'Name': item['Name'], 'Status': randrange(2)} for item in items]
```

If you're not familiar with list comprehensions and generator expressions I would recommend learning about them. They're a useful (and often very efficient) tool.

But beware that a one-liner is not always the best option. If the creation of the dictionaries gets more complex it's probably better to move it to its own function.

Also note that `'Status': (randrange(2))` does not need as many parentheses: `'Status': randrange(2)`.

---

**`display_data`**

I'd recommend cutting this down to a single `print` statement per loop iteration:

```
def display_data(data: list) -> None:
    for i in data:
        print("===", i, "===", sep="\n")
```

or even better

```
def display_data(data: list) -> None:
    line_sep = "==="
    for i in data:
        print(line_sep, i, line_sep, sep="\n")
```

---

**`main`**

Your first initialization of `curr` is immediately overwritten inside the loop, delete it.

`if item not in (prev)`, does not need parentheses: `if item not in prev`.

There are better (more readable and more efficient) ways to create `new`, which should be called `new_items` or `changed_items`:

- List comprehension: `new_items = [item for item in curr if item not in prev]`
- Functional approach: `new_items = list(filter(lambda item: item not in prev, curr))`

This also allows you to get rid of both `new = []` assignments, as these approaches will create an empty list if there are no new items.

You can replace `if len(new_items) > 0` by `if new_items`. [More about truthy and falsy values in Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/)

---

**Complete code**

```
import time
from random import randrange

temp_data = [{"Name": "SuperFish", "KeyID": "SecretCodeFish"},
             {"Name": "CowMan", "KeyID": "SecretCodeCow"}]


def change_data(items: list[dict]) -> list[dict]:
    return [{'Name': item['Name'], 'Status': randrange(2)} for item in items]


def display_data(data: list) -> None:
    line_sep = "==="
    for i in data:
        print(line_sep, i, line_sep, sep="\n")


def main():
    prev = change_data(temp_data)

    while True:
        time.sleep(3)

        curr = change_data(temp_data)

        new_items = [item for item in curr if item not in prev]

        if new_items:
            prev = curr
            display_data(new_items)
        else:
            print("NO CHANGES DETECTED")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Approach**

Please note that the current algorithm runs in O(n^2). Unfortunately `dict` is an unhashable type in Python. Therefore we cannot use `set`s to get around this, which would run in O(n). More on that approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486450/compute-list-difference).